# Want to show that $pz$ is a projection in a $C^*$-algebra with $q \le \frac{1}2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite von Neumann algebra acting on $B(H)$ and $p  \in A$ be a non-zero projection such that $p \notin A'$. Let $u =E(p)\in A \cap A'$ such that $u$ is not a projection, where $A'$ is the commutant of $A$ and $E$ is the center-valued trace. Since $u \in A\cap A'$, then the spectral projection $z=\mathbf 1_{\left(0,\frac{1}2\right]}(u) \in A \cap A'$ $($using bounded Borel functional calculus$).$ Also assuming that $z \ne 0$ and let $q=E(pz)$, where $E$ is the center-valued trace. Then prove that $pz$ is a  projection  with $q \le \frac{1}2$.

Clearly $pz$ is a projection, since both $p,z$ are projections and $z$ commutes with $p$. Now in order to show that $q \le \frac{1}2$, it enough to show $\left\langle \left( 1-2q\right)\xi,\xi\right\rangle \ge 0,$ for all $\xi \in H$. Only thing I know about $(1-2q)$ is that it i self adjoint and unable to prove that  $q \le \frac{1}2$. Please help me to solve this. Thanking you.

Note that, $\mathbf 1_{\left(0,\frac{1}2\right]}$ is the characteristic function of $\left(0,\frac{1}2\right]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $z$ is in the centre,
$$
E(pz)=E(p)z=u\,1_{(0,\frac12]}(u).
$$
Since $t\,1{(0,\frac12]}(t)\leq\frac12$ for all nonnegative $t$, functional calculus gives you
$$
E(pz)\leq\frac12.
$$

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer is all correct, but there was some mistake in my question. Instead of "$q=pz$" we have "$q=E(pz)$", where $E$ denotes the center-valued trace. I am sorry for the inconveniences. Now I corrected it in my question. Thanks.

Comment: That's not the only thing you have to change, then. C$^*$-algebras don't usually have a center-valued trace. You need a von Neumann algebra for that, and a finite one to boot.

Comment: You are right, I replaced C$^*$-algebra with finite von Neumann algebra for the existence of center-valued trace. And also I assume that $u=E(p)$, which meets all the conditons. Now any help is thankful.

Comment: Please see the edit.